# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'h3' ( Beautifulsoup )

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Web-scraping and I am following this tutorial ( https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/ ) to extract movie data, I think that I have badly defined " first_movie " !

this is the code

```
  from requests import get
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  first_movie =[]

  url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title? 
  release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1'
  response = get(url)
  html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
  type(html_soup)

  movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-advanced')

  first_name = first_movie.h3.a.text
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mov1.py", line 13, in <module>
first_name = first_movie.h3.a.text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'h3'
```

Comment: what you wanna do with h3?

Comment: @Jeppe That would not work, as `first_movie` has no elements, it's an empty list.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Sorry, I misread. `html_soup.find_all` returns a list. Each of these _may_ contain a h3. E.g. `movie_containers[0].h3.a.text`. [See documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_all` always returns a list.

Replace your code :

```
first_name = first_movie.h3.a.text
```

To

```
for movie in movie_containers:
  print(movie.find("h3").find("a").text)
```

O/P:

```
Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets
Baywatch
Darkest Hour
American Made
La Casa de Papel
Mindhunter
Transformers: The Last Knight
The Handmaid's Tale
The Lego Batman Movie
The Disaster Artist
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1'
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('h3',class_='lister-item-header')
for item in items:
    print(item.find('a').text)
```

Output:

```
Logan
Wonder Woman
Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2
Thor: Ragnarok
Dunkirk
Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi
Spider-Man: Homecoming
Get Out
Blade Runner 2049
Baby Driver
It
Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri
Justice League
The Shape of Water
John Wick: Chapter 2
Coco
Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle
Beauty and the Beast
Kong: Skull Island
Kingsman: The Golden Circle
Pirates of the Caribbean: Salazar's Revenge
Alien: Covenant
13 Reasons Why
War for the Planet of the Apes
The Greatest Showman
Life
Fast & Furious 8
Murder on the Orient Express
Lady Bird
Ghost in the Shell
King Arthur: Legend of the Sword
Wind River
The Hitman's Bodyguard
Mother!
The Mummy
Call Me by Your Name
Atomic Blonde
The Punisher
Bright
I, Tonya
Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets
Baywatch
Darkest Hour
American Made
La Casa de Papel
Mindhunter
Transformers: The Last Knight
The Handmaid's Tale
The Lego Batman Movie
The Disaster Artist
```

Answer (score 1):

`first_movie` is not assigned, replace `movie_containers` with it. use `find()` to select first element

```
first_movie = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-advanced')
first_name = first_movie.h3.a.text
```

or use `find_all()` with index

```
first_movie = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-advanced')[0]
first_name = first_movie.h3.a.text
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice short selector leveraging adjacent sibling combinator to get `a` tag next to class

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
titles = [item.text for item in soup.select('.lister-item-index + a')]
print(titles)
```